# How can I put particle fur of Blender to Maya export animation (abc)?

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles

I have a problem in my production: I made a particle system in Blender to generate fur on a character, then I animated it in Maya. Now I want to forward these particles on my character animated. I don't know how I can make it...can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "forward" the particles? Do you mean keep the Blender particles on the animated character?

Comment: Yes, I want! At this time, I have two shapes: one with my animation and the other with my particlessystem. I would like to combine them to export one mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Particle systems are application specific, and you won't be able to get the hair particles from Blender into Maya without making them meshes which you can do by hitting convert for the particle system modifier.

[image]

Comment: Can i keep this new mesh on the animated character in blender ?

Comment: @flamaboum Yes, you can keep the mesh hair on a character in Blender if that is what you are asking. You would have to parent that mesh to the head bone in your armature.